# Google api ruby client issue with the insert_calendar method

Tags: ruby, google-api-client

I am using the google code sample for the google calendar api. This code is supposed to make a new calendar using the google calendar api. I am not clear on how to get access to the insert_calendar method.

Does anybody know where did the client object come from in the results variable? What class does it come from?

```
calendar = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Calendar.new(
  summary: 'calendarSummary',
  time_zone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
)
result = client.insert_calendar(calendar)
print result.id
```

I don't know how to make a new one of those. When I make a new object like:

```
client = Google::APIClient.new
```

and I call methods, on it. I do not find an insert_calendar method. Can some one tell me what object I would need to instantiate in order to have the insert_calendar method?

This is a simple question but I am having a huge problem finding out how to answer this on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs page is [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google%2FApis%2FCalendarV3%2FCalendarService%3Ainsert_calendar). It looks like it's an instance method of `Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService`.

Since the usage isn't particularly clear from this documentation, I went to the [google-api-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/4e19ae601f6b7893ed7e388a119e1c6ce0d5bde7/generated/google/apis/calendar_v3/service.rb) source on Github and used the "search this repository" tool to find where `insert_calendar` is defined.

It's in [this file](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/4e19ae601f6b7893ed7e388a119e1c6ce0d5bde7/generated/google/apis/calendar_v3/service.rb).

From looking at the source & docs I can advise you try the following code (though I haven't verified this:

```
calendar = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Calendar.new(
  summary: 'calendarSummary',
  time_zone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
)

Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new.insert_calendar(
  calendar: calendar,
  # other options can go here
)
```